# Get field value User in Report on Custom object

Tags: user, custom-reports, joined-reports, report-formula

Is it possible in Saleforce lighting to have a report on a custom object and get a field value from the user object without adding a formulafield on the custom object or is there a way to add the formula in the report itself?

I googled but dint get an clear answer for the user object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every object will have createdby and lastmodifiedby field. Those fields  basically refers the User object. If you want to get any information related to them from User object, You can refer it by adding the fields from User object in the report layout.

Refer this document:- [Design the Field Layout for Reports Created From Your Custom Report Type](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=reports_report_type_layouts.htm&type=5)

Steps:-

1. From Setup, enter Report Types in the Quick Find box, then select
   Report Types to display the All Custom Report Types page.
2. Select the custom report type you want to edit and click Edit Layout
   on the Fields Available for Reports section.You can click Preview Layout to preview which fields will display on the Select Columns page of a report customized or run from this report type.
3. Select fields from the right-hand box and drag them to a section on
   the left.
4. Optionally, **click Add fields related via lookup** to display the Add
   Fields Via Lookup overlay. From here you can add fields via the
   lookup relationship the object selected in the View drop-down list
   has to other objects.

[image]

Comment: Hi Sanket, Have you tried this for a custom object related to the user object. I tried to make a custom report on the custom object and add the user object as related but I cannot select the user object.

Comment: I have highlighted that Object has relationship with User object via createdby and lastmodifiedby fields. You can only access information from user object related to createdby user and lastmodifiedby user.

Comment: Ok thanks, so in this case its not possible without creating a formulafield on the custom object to get the custom field value from the user object if i understand you correctly?

Comment: Yes, If you need value other than createdby and lastmodifiedby user detail, you have too. Even for that, you have to define the relationship.

Comment: Ok thanks for you explanation.